# Inverter diagonal principal multiplicando diagonal secundária

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

Estou desenvolvendo esse algoritmo, preciso inverter a diagonal principal e em seguida, multiplicar somente a diagonal secundária por 2, exemplo:

Ele está assim:

```
[9, 1, 2, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Preciso deixar ele assim:

```
[4, 1, 2, 8]
[5, 1, 14, 8]
[3, 4, 6, 0]
[2, 2, 3, 9]
```

Isso é o que tenho até agora:

```
dimensao = int(input())

matriz = []
for linha in range(dimensao):
    linha = [int(coluna) for coluna in input().split()]
    matriz.append(linha)
    
transposta = []
for linha in range(dimensao):
    transposta.append([])
    for coluna in range(dimensao):
        ent = matriz[coluna][linha]
        transposta[linha].append(ent)


for linha in transposta:
    for coluna in linha:
        print(coluna, end= ' ')
    print(end="\n")
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

Possivelmente existe uma maneira mais esperta pra fazer isso, mas de qualquer forma segue uma ideia:

```
matriz = [[9, 1, 2, 4],
          [5, 6, 7, 8],
          [3, 2, 1, 0],
          [1, 2, 3, 4]]
          
j = 0
tamanho_matriz = len(matriz)
lista = []

# Adicionando os elementos da diagonal principal a uma lista
for i in range(tamanho_matriz):
    lista.append(matriz[i][j])
    j = i + 1

# invertendo a lista da diagonal principal e adicionando os valores de volta na matriz
j = 0  
invertida = lista[::-1] # aqui acontece a inversão da lista
for i in range(tamanho_matriz):
    matriz[i][j] = invertida[i]
    j = i + 1

# multiplicando a diagonal secundaria    
j = tamanho_matriz - 1
for i in range(0, tamanho_matriz):
    matriz[i][j] = matriz[i][j] * 2
    j -= 1

# imprimindo a matriz
for i in range(tamanho_matriz):
    for j in range(tamanho_matriz):
        print(f'{matriz[i][j]:2} ', end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa complicar (aliás, nem sei porque você criou a matriz transposta, não tem nada a ver com o problema).

Bom, no seu código você usou a mesma variável `dimensao` para percorrer as linhas e colunas, então estou assumindo que sempre será uma matriz quadrada.

Como estamos interessados apenas nas diagonais, dá para simplificar os *loops*. Basta pensar que a diagonal principal são os elementos em que a linha é igual à coluna (ou seja, os elementos nas posições (0, 0), (1, 1), etc). Então só precisa de um *loop* para percorrer essas posições.

Depois, para inverter, basta trocar a primeira posição com a última (no caso, seria trocar a (0, 0) com a (3, 3)), depois trocar a segunda com a penúltima, e assim por diante. Desta forma, eu só preciso iterar até a metade da diagonal, que no final ela estará invertida.

Já para a diagonal secundária, o cálculo é diferente: na primeira linha, o elemento da diagonal secundária está na última coluna. Na segunda linha, é o elemento da penúltima coluna e assim por diante. Novamente, basta um *loop* pelas linhas, pois a coluna pode ser calculada. E aí é só percorrer todas as linhas e multiplicar o valor por 2.

Ficaria assim:

```py
# assumindo que as dimensões foram determinadas anteriormente e que a matriz já foi lida, etc
# assumindo também uma matriz quadrada
dimensao = 4
matriz = [
  [9, 1, 2, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [3, 2, 1, 0],
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
]

# diagonal principal, posições em que linha e coluna são iguais
# para inverter só precisa ir até a metade:
# troca o primeiro com o último, o segundo com o penúltimo, etc
for i in range(dimensao // 2): # "i" é a linha e a coluna
    dest = dimensao - i - 1 # posição que será trocada com esta
    matriz[i][i], matriz[dest][dest] = matriz[dest][dest], matriz[i][i]

# diagonal secundária
# primeira linha, última coluna; segunda linha, penúltima coluna, etc
for i in range(dimensao):
    matriz[i][dimensao - i - 1] *= 2 # multiplica por 2

print(*matriz, sep='\n')
```

Saída:

```
[4, 1, 2, 8]
[5, 1, 14, 8]
[3, 4, 6, 0]
[2, 2, 3, 9]
```

---

Também dá pra fazer tudo em um único *loop*. Só temos que garantir que a diagonal principal vá até a metade:

```py
matriz = [
  [9, 1, 2, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [3, 2, 1, 0],
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
]

for i in range(dimensao):
    dest = dimensao - i - 1
    if i < dimensao // 2:
        matriz[i][i], matriz[dest][dest] = matriz[dest][dest], matriz[i][i]
    matriz[i][dest] *= 2

print(*matriz, sep='\n')
```